# Next.js different 404 page for pages and for API calls

Tags: next.js

Is it possible to configure two different 404 pages in Next.js — one for rendered pages and another one for API routes? I want the 404 page for API calls to return in JSON format while for all other pages in HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible just you have to create a wildcard page under the api page route. For example you can create a page `page/api/[[...404]].js`. So, if no api route matches existing page it will show this page.